# How do I ask if I receive a bonus?

Tags: professionalism, bonus

In previous years, at the end of the financial year, I have received a bonus.
It's Now 7 days after EOFY and I still haven't received anything.
I don't expect one, but it would surely be helpful at the moment as I have a tax debt and car registration due.

I report to the CEO of the company and have a fairly relaxed relationship with him. Even though he's the only person who would provide a bonus, I think he'd still need approval from the board.

Without sounding disrespectful or rude, how does one ask a boss if a bonus might be given?

Comment: Why are you not expecting one?

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about asking *your manager*, who decides on your bonus? If that's not the case we can't help you, each company handles bonuses differently so we couldn't tell you who to ask.

Comment: Maybe just try to figure out through office talk if bonuses have been paid out yet. If they have you know where you are standing.

Comment: Not sure how the question is unclear - I'm asking 'how do I ask if I'm getting a bonus if I've received them in previous years but haven't got one yet?'

Comment: @smith - not expecting as in I understand that giving staff bonuses is choice he has, not that it's my right to receive one.   But I'd be lying if I wasn't hoping to get one because I have in previous years.

Answer (score 12):

The only way to do it is to ask nicely.  "Do I receive a bonus this year like previous years or is this year without a bonus?"  Hopefully this will lead to a discussion to where you find out either the company did not do well enough to give bonuses, or you didn't perform as great this year as the last year, or there is a policy change, etc...

Just be polite and ask, don't demand or say it's unfair, etc...

Comment: And if it is because of personal performance, it is completely appropriate to ask for feedback on what you could do better so you can earn one next year. This is your manager's job.

Comment: I like this suggestion, but I'd probably adopt it into the email suggestion on John's answer suggestion below.  Cheers

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your relationship with your boss...

If it's quite relaxed, just straight up ask:

> Hey boss, are we getting bonuses this year?

If it's quite a formal relationship, go with email:

> Hi Boss. As the financial year has drawn to a close, I was wondering if there is a bonus this year as per previous years? Thanks

Comment: I would personally go with e-mail regardless of the relationship.

Comment: I like your suggestion with the email - even though my relationship with my boss (who is also the CEO) is quite relaxed, we work in different offices and both have very busy days.  At least if it's an email, it give him time to reply without being put on the spot and without me shrinking into oblivion because I get so nervous asking about my performance or financial remuneration. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of ways to rephrase it , but the solution remains the same.
Go , and ask.
Just turn your question the best possible way regarding who you'll be asking , and the relation you have with this person.